# Is hijab obligatory in Islam?

Tags: quran, sharia, practical-islam, hijab

Is hijab an obligation(wajib) in Islam?

And is it obligatory on upon governments to propagate and enforce it?

Answer (score -2):

Quran gives a "code of conduct" for men and women interaction in public in [Surah-e-Noor](http://quran.com/24/30-31)

Two guidelines are same for men and women:

- Have modesty in their vision
- Guard their private parts

Following guidelines are for women only:

- Do not expose their adornment except that which [necessarily] appears thereof
- Wrap [a portion of] their headcovers over their chests
- Don't stamp their feet to make known what they conceal of their adornment

Thus "hijab" is not a religious obligation. Since it is not an obligation, it can not enforced by an islamic state. The only two things an islamic state CAN enforce by law is "salat" and "zakat", as mentioned in [Surah Al-Haj](http://quran.com/22/41). If a muslim is performing these two duties, he is a "muslim" in the eyes of the law of an islamic state.

For more details, refer to [this link](http://www.javedahmadghamidi.com/index.php/books/view/manners-for-man-woman-interaction-part-1-3)

Comment: you mean that if someone do not believe hijab(although quran says)he is muslem? and also why you differ between hijab and salat though both of them are ordered in quran?

Comment: As per the linked Al-Haj 41, you should elaborate on how hijab wouldn't fall under "enjoin what is right and forbid what is wrong" which is also the responsibility of an Islamic state.

Comment: @abdolah: please refer to the link in answer for details about the ayahs for order of hijab in quran

Comment: @goldPseudo: the word used in Quran for good in the ayah refer to general good things that are universally accepted as good things like honesty, not religious things

Comment: why you say hijab wouldn'n fall under "enjoin what is right and forbid what is wrong"? if it is wajib all wajib must be done by muslems so if anyone doesn't do it then we must enjoin him/her to hijab and forbid him/her from being unveiled.

Comment: @abdolah: as mentioned in my previous comment, the word used in Quran for good in the ayah refer to general good things that are universally accepted as good things like honesty, not religious things

Comment: you say that the goverment must not enforce to religous things? and also what does "mokar"(منکر) means? does not having hijab is not mokar?please see : [٥:٧٨] and [٥:٧٩] (excuse me for bad english)

Comment: @goto: "the word used in Quran for good in the ayah refer to general good things that are universa"lly accepted as good things like honesty, not religious things" Why do you distinguish between universally considered good and religious good at all? Isn't religion to tell us what is universally good and what is universally evil?

Comment: @infatuated : humans don't need religion to tell us that honesty is a good thing and telling lie us a bad thing. Allah has given this much guidance to each one of us

Comment: Still, we can't identify many virtues by and on our own average intellect. Hijab is one! Hence the need for enlightenment from above!

Comment: @infatuated ,but how can you identify which one is of which category?(to be universally accepted or to be wajib?)

Comment: Whatever Quran and the holy Prophet had required us to do in terms of deeds is Wajib and universally obligatory. Religion basically preaches us to do things that are universally good and beneficial to humankind.

Comment: you said :"Whatever Quran and the holy Prophet had required us to do in terms of deeds is Wajib", but yet how can you  identify which thing has been required and which is universally accepted? is the saying of Allah about them in quran is different? how you sure about hijab not to be wajib?